# k8s nginx ingress rewrite-target annotation not working as expected

Tags: mod-rewrite, nginx, kubernetes

Running in Minikube, I have the following ingress, with the necessary backend:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
        - path: /config/
          backend:
            serviceName: api-gateway
            servicePort: web
```

The intention is to serve the gateway's web UI, which expects the path to be `/`, otherwise it assumes the it is a logical path and attempts to forward the request to the correct microservice.

The rewrite of the path is not working as I expect it. It doesn't replace `/config/` with `/`. Am I misunderstanding [the example](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/examples/rewrite/README.md)?

In the logs of the nginx controller I see:

```
192.168.99.1 - [192.168.99.1] - - [13/Dec/2017:08:54:11 +0000] "GET /config HTTP/1.1" 301 185 "-" "curl/7.55.1" 78 0.000 [-] - - - -
192.168.99.1 - [192.168.99.1] - - [13/Dec/2017:08:54:11 +0000] "GET /config/ HTTP/1.1" 404 154 "-" "curl/7.55.1" 79 0.010 [dev-api-gateway-web] 172.17.0.10:8080 143 0.010 404
```

That's telling me that a request for `/config` got rewritten to `/config/` and resulted in a 404.

**How do I rewrite `/config` to `/`?**

Answer (score 4):

You are misunderstanding the example. With your configuration requests to the rewrite target `/` will be rewritten to `/config/`, not the other way around. So you need to switch paths: use `/config` as rewrite target, and set the `/` path in the rule.

So the rewrite target is always where the external requests go to, the rule path where the requests to the service/pod go to.

Comment: I though I might. If I put `/config` as the rewrite target, what happens to requests that don't contain `/config`? For example, a request for `/api`, supposing I have a rule and backend for `/api`?

Comment: You need another Ingress then, because an Ingress can only have 1 rewrite target. But you can have several Ingresses for the same host, that's no problem.

Comment: Is it not more accurate to say that the rewrite path (eg `/config`) gets replaced by `/` and then any any rules in the ingress will be applied according to the rewritten request path?

Comment: not sure if and how rewrite works with several rules... but I wouldn't expect that an Ingress with rewrite target `/config` can match any external requests to `/api`. I think a rule for `/api` would be matched by a request to `/config/api` then. But I never tried that.

Answer (score 2):

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
        - path: /config/(.+)
          backend:
            serviceName: api-gateway
            servicePort: web
```